# Have maven add dependency to target jar/lib

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven

Is it possible to have maven create a statically linked jar?

I have a specific design pattern I'd like to enforce regarding my JPA entities and the library that depends on them.

In my design pattern I have a library project that provides `entity` and would like to have a separate project project provide `entity-ejb`.  In this way I would be able to develop an additional distinct project using only the `entity` classes and non of the JPA implementation.

This works fine in theory and practice with manual classpath resolution.  I am however finding maven to be rather frustrating in this regard.  I can't seem to add the dependency jar file to the ejb/lib folder using maven.

---

I have tried using the

```
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
```

to copy the dependancy to the target/classes directory folder.  Unfortunately it does not appear this folder is jarred directly.

Thoughts and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're after exactly, but it sounds like the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) might be what you need. You can provide this plugin with an assembly descriptor (an xml file) that details the type of assembly file (e.g. a jar, a war, a binary zip, etc.) as well as the exact composition of that file. You can package things in the assembly in any way you like, include/exclude any file, create directory structures, etc.

There's a good description and some practical examples on the linked page that should get you started.